# How to merge mp3 and mp4 in python / Mute a mp4 file and add a mp3 file on it

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I want to merge an mp3 and an mp4 in python, if possible with the moviepy library.

But my mp4 video got some sound in it, so i want to delete this sound before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got a lot of difficulties to find something that work, so i think a lot of people could have this difficulties too, so here is the code that worked for me :

````
def combine_audio(vidname, audname, outname, fps=60): 
    import moviepy.editor as mpe
    my_clip = mpe.VideoFileClip(vidname)
    audio_background = mpe.AudioFileClip(audname)
    final_clip = my_clip.set_audio(audio_background)
    final_clip.write_videofile(outname,fps=fps)

combine_audio("test.mp4", "test.mp3", "test_over.mp4") # i create a new file
combine_audio("test.mp4", "test.mp3", "test.mp4") # i rewrite on the same file```
````

Comment: Whenever I do this, the video freezes after one second but sound continues